# Acercamiento o alejamiento según el botón pulsado

Tags: javascript, html, eventos

Poseo el siguiente código para alejar o acercar (ZOOM IN, ZOOM OUT) con un click en Javascript

**Para acercar:**

```
    window.onclick = function(e) {
    var coef = e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey ? 0.5 : 2,
        oz = current.zoom,
        nz = (current.zoom *= coef),
        /// calculate click at current zoom
        ix = (e.clientX - current.x) / oz,
        iy = (e.clientY - current.y) / oz,
        /// calculate click at new zoom
        nx = ix * nz,
        ny = iy * nz,
        /// move to the difference
        cx = (current.x = ix - nx),
        cy = (current.y = iy - ny)
    ;
    /// make sure we translate before scale!
    con.style.transform
        = 'translate('+cx+'px, '+cy+'px) '
        + 'scale('+nz+')'
    ;
};
```

**Para alejar:**

```
    window.onclick = function(e) {
    var coef = e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey ? 0.5 : 2,
        oz = current.zoom,
        nz = (current.zoom *= coef),
        /// calculate click at current zoom
        ix = (e.clientX - current.x) / oz,
        iy = (e.clientY - current.y) / oz,
        /// calculate click at new zoom
        nx = ix * nz,
        ny = iy * nz,
        /// move to the difference
        cx = (current.x = ix - nx),
        cy = (current.y = iy - ny)
    ;
    /// make sure we translate before scale!
    con.style.transform
        = 'translate('+cx+'px, '+cy+'px) '
        + 'scale('+nz+')'
    ;
};
```

Ahora, deseo un simple cambio, según el botón pulsado realizar el alejamiento y el alejamiento. Al pulsar el botón izquierdo realizar el acercamiento, al pulsar el botón derecho alejar. Todo esto conservando el código de acercamiento y alejamiento que presento arriba. Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que se está preguntando es acerca de cómo diferenciar con cual botón se hizo clic. Para ello nos sirve el evento `mousedown` el cual asigna a la propiedad `which` los valores siguientes:

1: Si se hace clic con el botón izquierdo.
2: Si se hace clic con el botón central.
3: Si se hace clic con el botón derecho.

A continuación un ejemplo sencillo:

Se muestra un mensaje de alerta específico según se haga clic con el botón izquierdo, central o derecho sobre el texto.

```js
var zona = document.getElementById('zona');
zona.addEventListener('mousedown',valida);
function valida(e){
  switch(e.which){
    case 1:
      alert('¡Error! Hiciste click con el botón izquierdo');
      break;
    case 2:
      alert('¡Error! Hiciste click con el botón central');
      break;
    case 3:
      alert('¡Correcto!');
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="zona">Haz clic con el botón derecho aquí</div>
```